Conenct PWA with the magento 2
I have successfully installed Magento 2.4.5 and the PWA as well.
Now I am configuring the PWA with the Magento.
I have changed the Backend_URL in the .env
also installed the Upward module , apply configs
But it is not integrating.
Can Anybody helps me to fix this.
When I run PWA it shows me this

